# T-SQL Order by skews results

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-order-by

SQL Server 2008 Enterprise Edition.

I am getting some odd behavior trying to return results from a table variable, and concat them into a single string.

```
declare @SQLString nvarchar(max) ='';   
declare @List table (ID smallint, Period smallint, Name nvarchar(4000), Value    nvarchar(4000) );

insert into @List values(1, 0, 'Column1', 'Total Value');
insert into @List values(1, 0, 'Column2', 'Cost');
insert into @List values(1, 0, 'Column3/Column2', 'Qty');
insert into @List values(1, 0, 'Column4', 'Test');

select @SQLString = @SQLString + ',' + char(13) + char(9)
 + 'isnull('+Name + ',0) as [' + Value +']'
    from @List order by Period, ID
```

At the moment, this is returning only the LAST result from `@List` into `@SQLString`.

If I remove the `order by`, it works perfectly. Ie. it returns all rows into the string (eg. isnull(1,0), isnull(2,0) etc)

I have done this 1000 times for other purposes. What am I missing?

It does however, work on my local machine (running SQL Server 2008 Developer)

Comment: Can you provide some sample data? I tried with some dummy data and it works fine. Returns all the rows

Comment: What should be your expected Output?

Comment: Can't replicate the problem.

Comment: Expected output is ,  isnull(Column1,0) as [Total Value],  isnull(Column2,0) as [Cost],  isnull(Column3/Column2,0) as [Qty],  isnull(Column4,0) as [Test]